# RCP Handler enabledWhen based on Resource type

Tags: java, eclipse

i had written a plugin for eclipse based on Eclipse 3 RCP. I injected the context menu of the editor and want that a specific menu item only is enabled if the type of the resource is correct.

The type of the file is ->

```
com.test.test.resources.test.testphysical.TESTSequentialDataSet
```

which is instance of ->

```
com.test.test.resources.test.testphysical.TESTResource
```

Now what I had tried:

```xml
<handler  
       class="com.test.test.handler.TESTHandler"
       commandId="com.test.test.commands.COBQS">      
     <enabledWhen>
         <with variable="activeEditorInput">
            <iterate>
               <instanceof
                     value="com.test.test.resources.test.testphysical.TESTSequentialDataSet">
               </instanceof>
            </iterate>
         </with>
    </enabledWhen>
</handler>
```

But this doesnt worked for me =/ Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: e4 parts don't have an activeEditorInput. So just to check - your 'editor' is just an MPart, not a class extending IEditorPart?

Comment: No my editor is extending IEditorPart

Comment: Then this is an Eclipse 3.x application, not Eclipse 4 'e4'.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that :/ I corrected it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`activeEditorInput` is not a list so you can't use `iterate`.

The editor input will be a class implementing `IEditorInput` not your object.

Use something like:

```xml
<with variable="activeEditorInput">
    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
         <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.contentTypeId" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaSource" />
    </adapt>
</with>
```

The `adapt` element uses the adapter manager to get the file from the editor input.

The test is using the 'content type id' for the file - I have used the Java source file id here, you will have to define a content type id for your file type.

Comment: This works fine thanks. I have got another question. Whats wrong with this code?´<enabledWhen>
        <with variable="activeEditorInput">
       <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
            <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.path" value="Remote*" />
       </adapt>
   </with>
     </enabledWhen>´

Comment: `org.eclipse.core.resources.path` matches the result of `IResource.getFullPath()` which will be something like '/project/folder/file'

Comment: Okay. And if I got a path like RemoteSyntaxCheck/xx/xx/xx/xx, the value="Remote*" should match it right or?

Comment: No, it must be the **full** path of a file in the workspace. It does not match substrings. You can use `org.eclipse.core.resources.name` to match a file name, or `org.eclipse.core.resources.extension` to match a file extension.

Comment: [link]http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_expressions.htm[/link] There it says that wild cards are supported :/

Comment: Yes, I was just checking that * and ? are allowed - but the path will always start with '/'